# Default choices in "Bandersnatch"

Tags: black-mirror, black-mirror-bandersnatch

The information that can be found regarding [Black Mirror: Bandersnatch](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt09495224/) default choices path (i.e. when the viewer is watching the film without any interaction) seems to be contradictory.

On the one hand [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Mirror:_Bandersnatch#Design_and_writing) (based on an Hollywood Reporter article) states that:

> If no choices are selected, the viewer will get the most basic version
>   of the story, as determined by Brooker

On the other hand I found this on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/blackmirror/comments/aa98fs/bandersnatch_endings_thread/ecrtbio):

> I think you can get all the endings if u don t choose anything -
>   making it apparently 320 min long as it was rumored. If u don t choose
>   anything, the show chooses for you, even making different choices and
>   going back for the different endings.

The latter was also confirmed by a person I talked to, that did abstain from choices during watching (although that person wasn't absolutely sure).

The problem is that you cannot have *the most basic version of the story* and multiple "proper" endings (with credits) at the same time.

What is the behaviour of *Bandersnatch* when you abstain from making any choices and what is the default path from the start to the ending credits (or at least which ending is the default one)?

Comment: Why dont you just watch it & make no choices and find out the default path. This question is like asking the plot of the movie without watching the movie. I don't know if any traditional close reason applies.

Comment: Of course the code that drives the choices may contain random choices not *default* choices. Moreover, if this is true and future choices depend on previous choices, it may be impossible to even define what "default" means as randomness might lead to many different paths of different length through the story.

Comment: @KharoBangdo Of course I can do it, but the fact that I don't want to (reasons not relevant) doesn't make this question invalid in my opinion. I think there may be more people interested that would benefit from the potential answers.

Comment: @matt_black If the choices are randomly selected I'll accept the answer with any source confirming this.

Comment: Sound valid question to me with only two possible answers: 1) it's random or 2) this is the default path